# How can I change the order of an alphabetic enumeration?

Tags: lists, enumerate, sorting, welsh

For instance, in Welsh the alphabet starts a, b, c, ch, d, dd, etc.

Is there a way to automatically alter the ordering of lists to match this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could define a command for this purpose. Use that command in defining the label. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\welsh[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or ch\or d\or dd\or ... \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand*\Welsh[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or A\or B\or C\or ... \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\welsh{\value{enumi}}}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That does the trick perfectly.  Diolch yn fawr!